# add button to outlook message tab using custom ui xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am able to add button to file menu backstage view, but I also want to add it to the message tab or show my custom button on the next row of the toolbar.  Is this possible, or are there any betters ways to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the xml code and it worked for me. Hope it helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabReadMessage">
        <group id="GroupNew" label="My Group" insertBeforeMso="GroupClipboard">
          <button id="buttonid" size="large" label="my button" onAction="mybutton_click" imageMso="HappyFace"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```